# PHP 7.1.2 compilation and libcurl error

Tags: php, compilation, debian, libcurl

PHP 7.1.2 is here, i tried to compile it as usually but this time ./configure fail with these error:

> checking for cURL in default path... not found
>   configure: error: Please reinstall the libcurl distribution -
>       easy.h should be in /include/curl/

I'm on Debian Stretch (9).

I found `libcurl4-openssl-dev` is installed in /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl`when`./configure`expect it in`/include/curl/`

libcurl4-openssl-dev on debian Jessie install curl in /usr/include/curl/ when Stretch install curl in /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl.

With the last PHP version I compiled (7.1.1), I had no problems, but this time it failed.

To compile:

```
./buildconf --force && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php --with-config-file-path=/etc/php/lib --enable-bcmath --with-bz2 --with-zlib --enable-zip --enable-calendar --enable-exif --enable-ftp --with-gettext --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-freetype-dir --with-xpm-dir --enable-mbstring --enable-mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --with-openssl --enable-intl --enable-soap --with-readline --with-curl --with-mcrypt --with-xsl --enable-sockets
```

`curl` and `libcurl4-openssl-dev` packages are installed

I tried with --with-curl=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl/ but it doesn't work.

I don't know how to solve this, can someone knows please ?

Comment: look closer in the `config.log` file after the failure to get more specific details about the failed check

Answer (score 8):

A temporary solution is to create a sym link at `/usr/local/include/curl` pointing to `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl` and to compile PHP with `--with-curl=/usr/local`.

Example: command from within `/usr/local/include` as user `root` or using `sudo
ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl curl`.

For others searching this problem, replace `x86_64` with your architecture.

I can not tell you if it is a bug, or unintended consequence of updates to the `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` and `libcurl4-openssl-dev` packages. You will notice that if you try to compile the previous versions of PHP, they now will also fail with the missing curl error, because simply, the new development packages do not create the required files where PHP expects them.

I call it a temporary solution as future updates in Debian may fix this by placing a symlink or something at `/usr/include/curl` pointing to your default architecture, or maybe the PHP configure script will get updated. The reason you use `--with-curl=/usr/local` is that the PHP configuration script wants "what you specify", and appends `/include/curl`.

Answer (score 3):

You should install the [`libcurl4-gnutls-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libcurl4-gnutls-dev) package.

> This package provides the development files (ie. includes, static library, manual pages) that allow one to build software which uses `libcurl`.

To install `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` :

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

Comment: I tried but it change nothing. Installing libcurl4-gnutls-dev remove libcurl4-openssl-dev. Files requested by php are installed (easy.h) but not in the path expected. It's "new", until 7.1.2 i used to compile every new php version that way and it works every time. But this time i can't compile PHP because of path not matching by requirements.

Comment: @krazitchek try it with `./configure --prefix=/usr`

Comment: Nothing change, same error. I'm not sure but i think something change in libcurl4-openssl-dev package in debian 8 jessie  (https://packages.debian.org/fr/jessie/amd64/libcurl4-openssl-dev/filelist) and debian 9 stretch (https://packages.debian.org/fr/stretch/amd64/libcurl4-openssl-dev/filelist). We can see on those two urls that path is not the same for the same package. Jessie version match requirement (/usr/include/curl/easy.h) while stretch version don't match requirement (/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl/easy.h).